# European/french thousand separator in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to format the y axis in a ggplot graph with a space (and not a comma) as thousand separator `;` something like 10 000 and not 10,000.
I can't found it in the `scale_y_continuous` help.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I know this sort of stuff is subjective, but I would encourage you to use 1E1, 1E2, etc. instead (or 1.0*10^N if that's more pleasing).  Long numeric strings that don't provide additional precision aren't all that useful.

Comment: Sort of mysterious why `ggplot2` does not comply with the ISU by default. These days most journals demand it.

Answer (score 11):

As @David and @joran just said.

First, define the label formatter:

```
space <- function(x, ...) { 
  format(x, ..., big.mark = " ", scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
}
```

and then use it with `scale_y_continous`:

```
plot + scale_y_continuous(labels = space)
```

Comment: this add a normal space as a separator, but usually, the space is smaller ? can you think of a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just taking a stab in the dark, but `scale_y_continuous(labels = space)` might do the trick.

Comment: I don't think there is a `space` label formatter in the **scales** package, but it wouldn't be very difficult to write one. Just use `comma_format` as a template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, Joran.

Comment: @user2035816 Use `@joran` so that he can get notified whenever you reply to him. Also, do close the question since it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @user2035816 And do remember to close the question once you're finished.