# Change the thousands separator in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal, scale, separator

While making a bar plot with ggplot I run into troubles getting the preferred thousands separator. I would like thousands to be separated by a dot instead of a comma. Like this it gives no separator:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales) 
options(scipen=10)
D = data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1000001,500000))
p = ggplot(D,aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") 
p
```

and like this it gives a comma:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
```

How do you get a dot as thousands separator? I can't find documentation on which types of other labels exist besides some examples on http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_continuous.html.

Thanks in advance,

Forza

Comment: What's `comma` in `labels=comma`? Its an undefined variable, thats what it is...

Comment: @Spacedman it works and it is well defined. You can also see an example of it being used in the official documentation. Do you have the newest version of ggplot? You need to use library(scales), btw.

Comment: Its from the `scales` package. I see your edit now.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Didn't know you could pass on functions to labels as well, that's useful.

Comment: If you type `comma` you'll see that it is a function very similar to the answer given. Perhaps suggest to the `scales` package author a `dottedThousands` function?

Comment: Find the github repo for scales (if it exists), add new issue. Otherwise email maintainer.

Comment: I'd like to add, that it's often necessary to add the trim option (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665461/european-french-thousand-separator-in-ggplot) to the function on the x axis, as the format might move the axis values to the right. Thus they do not align any longer.

Answer (score 23):

this also works:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Answer (score 12):

Very good answer. As you are defining a thousands separator, it is better to also define the decimal separator as a comma, to avoid errors.

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler answer than the ones provided is:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = '.'))
```